# using typedef in template instantiation and extern template declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef, extern

There are two cases where `typedef` confuses me when it comes to `extern template declaration` and `explicit template instantiation`.

To illustrate the two see below 2 example code snippets.

Consider following example **(Case 1)**:

```
// suppose following code in some cpp file    
template <typename T>
    struct example
{
    T value;
};

// valid typedefs
typedef example<int> int_example;
typedef example<std::string> string_example;

// explicit instantiation using above typedefs
template class int_example; // -> compile time error
template class string_example; // -> compile time error

// instead we need to use type names
template class example<int>; // -> OK
template class example<std::string>; // -> OK

// QUESTION 1: Why does this work however? is this valid code?
typedef std::string type_string;
template class example<type_string>;
```

Why does the `template class example<type_string>` work with typedef ? and why is it valid while `template class string_example` is not?

Consider following example **(Case 2)**:

```
// suppose following code is in some header file
template <typename T>
struct example
{
    T value;
};

// valid typedefs
typedef std::string type_string;
typedef example<type_string> string_example;

// Explicit instantiation declaration
// QUESTION 2: Is this valid code? if not why not?
extern template string_example; // -> at least this compiles, but is it OK?
```

As questioned in the comment above, is it valid to use typedef in `extern template declaration`, like in the example above, and why does this compile unlike the **Case1** where it does not.

I've read about similar cases but none gives the detailed answer to above 2 questions. detailed elaboration is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template class int_example;
```

is not legal. From the C++11 Stanard:

> **14.7.2 Explicit instantiation**
>
> 2 The syntax for explicit instantiation is:
>
> *explicit-instantiation:*
> `extern`<sub>opt</sub> `template` *declaration*
>
> There are two forms of explicit instantiation: an explicit instantiation definition and an explicit instantiation declaration. An explicit instantiation declaration begins with the `extern` keyword.
>
> 3 If the explicit instantiation is for a class or member class, the *elaborated-type-specifier* in the *declaration* shall include a *simple-template-id.*

*simple-template-id* is defined in Section **A.12 Templates** as:

> *simple-template-id:*
> *template-name* `<` *template-argument-list*<sub>opt</sub> `>`

`int_example` does not qualify as a *simple-template-id*.
`example<int>` does qualify as a *simple-template-id*.

However, by that logic,

```
extern template string_example;
```

is not legal either. I don't know how it works for you. I got the following error when I tried to compile such a line in g++ 4.9.3.

```
socc.cc:15:31: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
 extern template string_example; // -> compile time error
```

Comment: do you know why `template class example<type_string>;` and `extern template class example<type_string>;`works (or it does not with GCC), I'm using MSVC-140 btw and it works. thanks so much!

Comment: `example<type_string>` qualifies as a *simple-template-id*.

Comment: thanks, I've done some tests with GCC and there are cases where g++ issues undefined references for cases such as `example<type_string>` but msvc compiles just fine, there are also cases where msvc gives warnings but not g++, obviously this cases are neither described nor well defined by standard.